# Merging values together to one key in an Ordered Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

So I was wondering if there was a much more elegant solution to the one I have implemented right now into merging values of an ordered dict.

I have an ordered dict that looks like this

```
'fields': OrderedDict([
    ("Sample Code", "Vendor Sample ID"),
    ("Donor ID", "Vendor Subject ID"),
    ("Format", "Material Format"),
    ("Sample Type", "Sample Type"),
    ("Age", "Age"),
    ("Gender", "Gender"),
    ("Ethnicity/ Race", "Race"),
]),
```

If I pass in a parameter like so as a list

```
[2,3] or [2,4,5]
```

is there an elegant way to merge the values together under a new key so

```
[2,3], "Random_Key"
```

would return

```
'fields': OrderedDict([
        ("Sample Code", "Vendor Sample ID"),
        ("Donor ID", "Vendor Subject ID"),
        **("Random Key", "Material Format Sample Type"),**
        ("Age", "Age"),
        ("Gender", "Gender"),
        ("Ethnicity/ Race", "Race"),
    ]),
```

while also deleting the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: at least an interesting question about dictionaries in 2018. I wish that you cut down your input data a little more. Too many values is drowning the diffs between start & end dict.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can do that!

Comment: see: looks even nicer like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done nicely with a generator.

This generator yields the key item pair if it doesn't have to be squashed, and if it has, it saves the items till the last entry, and then yields it, with a new key and the saved items joined.

With the generator a new OrderedDict can be constructed.

```
from collections import OrderedDict    

def sqaushDict(d, ind, new_key):
    """ Takes an OrderedDictionary d, and yields its key item pairs, 
    except the ones at an index in indices (ind), these items are merged 
    and yielded at the last position of indices (ind) with a new key (new_key)
    """
    if not all(x < len(d) for x in ind):
        raise IndexError ("Index out of bounds")
    vals = []
    for n, (k, i), in enumerate(d.items()):
        if n in ind:
            vals += [i]
            if n == ind[-1]:
                yield (new_key, " ".join(vals))
        else:
            yield (i, k)

d = OrderedDict([
    ("Sample Code", "Vendor Sample ID"),
    ("Donor ID", "Vendor Subject ID"),
    ("Format", "Material Format"),
    ("Sample Type", "Sample Type"),
    ("Age", "Age"),
    ("Gender", "Gender"),
])

t = OrderedDict(squashDict(d, [2, 3], "Random"))
print(t)
```

Comment: This is definitely in route of what I wanted thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sure there's an elegant way. `OrderedDict` has a `move_to_end` method to move keys at start or end, but not at a random position.

I'd try to be as efficient as possible, and minimze loops

- get a list of the keys
- find the index of the key you want to merge with the following one
- remove the next key of the dictionary
- create a list with `d` items
- alter this list with the new value at the stored index
- rebuild an `OrderedDict` from it

like this (I removed some keys because it shortens the example):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([
    ("Sample Code", "Vendor Sample ID"),
    ("Donor ID", "Vendor Subject ID"),
    ("Format", "Material Format"),
    ("Sample Type", "Sample Type"),
    ("Age", "Age"),
    ("Gender", "Gender"),
])

lk = list(d.keys())
index = lk.index("Sample Type")
v = d.pop(lk[index+1])

t = list(d.items())
t[index] = ("new key",t[index][1]+" "+v)

d = OrderedDict(t)

print(d)
```

result:

> OrderedDict([('Sample Code', 'Vendor Sample ID'), ('Donor ID', 'Vendor Subject ID'), ('Format', 'Material Format'), ('new key', 'Sample Type Age'), ('Gender', 'Gender')])

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this by sorting the indices descending, then you can use `dict.pop(key,None)` to retreive and remove the key/value at once, but I decided against it, append the values in the order the occured in `indices`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

def mergeEm(d,indices,key):
    """Merges the values at index given by 'indices' on OrderedDict d into a list.        
    Appends this list with key as key to the dict. Deletes keys used to build list."""

    if not all(x < len(d) for x in indices):
        raise IndexError ("Index out of bounds")

    vals = []                      # stores the values to be removed in order
    allkeys = list(d.keys())
    for i in indices:
        vals.append(d[allkeys[i]])   # append to temporary list
    d[key] = vals                  # add to dict, use ''.join(vals) to combine str
    for i in indices:              # remove all indices keys
        d.pop(allkeys[i],None)
    pprint(d)


fields= OrderedDict([
    ("Sample Code", "Vendor Sample ID"),
    ("Donor ID", "Vendor Subject ID"),
    ("Format", "Material Format"),
    ("Sample Type", "Sample Type"),
    ("Age", "Age"),
    ("Gender", "Gender"),
    ("Ethnicity/ Race", "Race"),
    ("Sample Type", "Sample Type"),
    ("Organ", "Organ"),
    ("Pathological Diagnosis", "Diagnosis"),
    ("Detailed Pathological Diagnosis", "Detailed Diagnosis"),
    ("Clinical Diagnosis/Cause of Death", "Detailed Diagnosis option 2"),
    ("Dissection", "Dissection"),
    ("Quantity (g, ml, or ug)", "Quantity"),
    ("HIV", "HIV"),
    ("HEP B", "HEP B")
])
pprint(fields)
mergeEm(fields, [5,4,2], "tata")
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Sample Code', 'Vendor Sample ID'),
             ('Donor ID', 'Vendor Subject ID'),
             ('Format', 'Material Format'),
             ('Sample Type', 'Sample Type'),
             ('Age', 'Age'),
             ('Gender', 'Gender'),
             ('Ethnicity/ Race', 'Race'),
             ('Organ', 'Organ'),
             ('Pathological Diagnosis', 'Diagnosis'),
             ('Detailed Pathological Diagnosis', 'Detailed Diagnosis'),
             ('Clinical Diagnosis/Cause of Death',
              'Detailed Diagnosis option 2'),
             ('Dissection', 'Dissection'),
             ('Quantity (g, ml, or ug)', 'Quantity'),
             ('HIV', 'HIV'),
             ('HEP B', 'HEP B')])


OrderedDict([('Sample Code', 'Vendor Sample ID'),
             ('Donor ID', 'Vendor Subject ID'),
             ('Sample Type', 'Sample Type'),
             ('Ethnicity/ Race', 'Race'),
             ('Organ', 'Organ'),
             ('Pathological Diagnosis', 'Diagnosis'),
             ('Detailed Pathological Diagnosis', 'Detailed Diagnosis'),
             ('Clinical Diagnosis/Cause of Death',
              'Detailed Diagnosis option 2'),
             ('Dissection', 'Dissection'),
             ('Quantity (g, ml, or ug)', 'Quantity'),
             ('HIV', 'HIV'),
             ('HEP B', 'HEP B'),
             ('tata', ['Gender', 'Age', 'Material Format'])])
```